# Trying to add numbers in XSLT to create a total with some numbers undefined

Tags: xslt, nan, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to make a yearly sales total for individual items in our system software that my company has monthly totals. I'm doing this by editing an already existing xsl file, so most of the code is not mine. The issue I am having is it only works for years that each of the 12 months are defined. During the current year for instance, there is no data for august through December and the total is calculated as NaN. I'm new to XSLT, but I have researched a lot before coming here to ask. Here is what my added code looks like

```
        <!-- For each field value -->
        <xsl:for-each select="/zoom/query6[generate-id() = generate-id(key('rows-by-loc',concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr))[1])]">
          <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
            <!-- <xsl:for-each select="./*">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(name()='STK_LOC_ID') or 
                          (name()='mo') or
                          (name()='yr')">
           -->
            <TD BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
                    <SMALL><xsl:value-of select="STK_LOC_ID"/></SMALL>
            </TD>
            <TD BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <SMALL>
                <xsl:value-of select="yr"/>
              </SMALL>
            </TD>
            <TD ID="MEASURE" BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <xsl:attribute name="Sales"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'January'))/Sales" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Qty_Sold"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'January'))/Qty_Sold" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'January'))/Qty_Sold"/>
            </TD>
            <TD ID="MEASURE" BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <xsl:attribute name="Sales"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'February'))/Sales" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Qty_Sold"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'February'))/Qty_Sold" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'February'))/Qty_Sold"/>
            </TD>
            <TD ID="MEASURE" BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <xsl:attribute name="Sales"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'March'))/Sales" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Qty_Sold"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'March'))/Qty_Sold" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'March'))/Qty_Sold"/>
            </TD>
            <TD ID="MEASURE" BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <xsl:attribute name="Sales"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'April'))/Sales" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Qty_Sold"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'April'))/Qty_Sold" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'April'))/Qty_Sold"/>
            </TD>
            <TD ID="MEASURE" BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <xsl:attribute name="Sales"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'May'))/Sales" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Qty_Sold"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'May'))/Qty_Sold" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'May'))/Qty_Sold"/>
            </TD>
            <TD ID="MEASURE" BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <xsl:attribute name="Sales"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'June'))/Sales" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Qty_Sold"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'June'))/Qty_Sold" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'June'))/Qty_Sold"/>
            </TD>
            <TD ID="MEASURE" BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <xsl:attribute name="Sales"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'July'))/Sales" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Qty_Sold"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'July'))/Qty_Sold" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'July'))/Qty_Sold"/>
            </TD>
            <TD ID="MEASURE" BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <xsl:attribute name="Sales"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'August'))/Sales" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Qty_Sold"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'August'))/Qty_Sold" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'August'))/Qty_Sold"/>
            </TD>
            <TD ID="MEASURE" BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <xsl:attribute name="Sales"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'September'))/Sales" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Qty_Sold"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'September'))/Qty_Sold" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'September'))/Qty_Sold"/>
            </TD>
            <TD ID="MEASURE" BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <xsl:attribute name="Sales"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'October'))/Sales" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Qty_Sold"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'October'))/Qty_Sold" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'October'))/Qty_Sold"/>
            </TD>
            <TD ID="MEASURE" BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <xsl:attribute name="Sales"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'November'))/Sales" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Qty_Sold"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'November'))/Qty_Sold" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'November'))/Qty_Sold"/>
            </TD>
            <TD ID="MEASURE" BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <xsl:attribute name="Sales"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'December'))/Sales" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Qty_Sold"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'December'))/Qty_Sold" /></xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'December'))/Qty_Sold"/>
            </TD>
    <TD ID="MEASURE" BGCOLOR="White" STYLE="height: 8px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt;" WIDTH="1%">
              <xsl:attribute name="Sales"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'December'))/Sales + key('rows-by-locmo', 
        concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'November'))/Sales + key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'October'))/Sales + key('rows-by-locmo', 
        concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'September'))/Sales + key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'August'))/Sales + key('rows-by-locmo', 
        concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'July'))/Sales + key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'June'))/Sales + key('rows-by-locmo', 
        concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'May'))/Sales + key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'April'))/Sales + key('rows-by-locmo', 
        concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'March'))/Sales + key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'February'))/Sales + key('rows-by-locmo', 
        concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'January'))/Sales" /></xsl:attribute>

              <xsl:attribute name="Qty_Sold"><xsl:value-of select="key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'December'))/Qty_Sold + key('rows-by-locmo', 
        concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'November'))/Qty_Sold + key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'October'))/Qty_Sold + key('rows-by-locmo', 
        concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'September'))/Qty_Sold + key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'August'))/Qty_Sold + key('rows-by-locmo', 
        concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'July'))/Qty_Sold + key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'June'))/Qty_Sold + key('rows-by-locmo', 
        concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'May'))/Qty_Sold + key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'April'))/Qty_Sold + key('rows-by-locmo', 
        concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'March'))/Qty_Sold + key('rows-by-locmo', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'February'))/Qty_Sold + key('rows-by-locmo', 
        concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr,'January'))/Qty_Sold " /></xsl:attribute>

            </TD>
```

I've tried to make a variable for each month and then test it, but as soon as I add a variable the form in the system doesn't work. Thanks! Here is also the SQL code for the query

```
/*FIELDS_BEGIN*/ITEM_NO, STK_LOC_ID, PriorMonths, mo, yr, Sales, Qty_Sold/*FIELDS_END*/
/*NAME_BEGIN Monthly History NAME_END*/
FROM VI_PS_ITEM_LOC_MONTHLY_HIST
WHERE PriorMonths <= 35 and ITEM_NO =:self
order by yr
```

Comment: What does your XML look like? You can't add a value that doesn't exist so one way to get around it is to see if it exists or is empty and then set it to a default value of zero and then sum all of those values.

Comment: What the system basically does is it makes a SQL query for the past 35 months of data. Then it uses the xsl to format the data. I can show you the sql code, but I'm not sure that will help.        SELECT

/*FIELDS_BEGIN*/ITEM_NO, STK_LOC_ID, PriorMonths, mo, yr, Sales, Qty_Sold/*FIELDS_END*/
/*NAME_BEGIN Monthly History NAME_END*/
FROM VI_PS_ITEM_LOC_MONTHLY_HIST
WHERE PriorMonths <= 35 and ITEM_NO =:self

Comment: You need to show enough code (XML and XSLT) to enable us to reproduce your problem. -- P.S. Edit your question, don't post code in comments.

Comment: ok, I have added a lot more information. I would just try to do the addition in sql, but the xslt takes both the QTY_SOLD and SALES from the same report, then formats them separately in the software with a dropdown box to select them.

Comment: Could you include the variable definition that you've tried? What do the entries for the single months August through December show?

Comment: Please show more codes. Should be able to fix easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify things, consider the following very basic XML

```
<root>
   <a year="2014" month="jan"><sales>100</sales></a>
   <a year="2014" month="feb"><sales>200</sales></a>
</root>
```

Then your problem can be recreated with this, also basic, XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:key name="year" match="a" use="concat(@year, @month)" />
   <xsl:param name="year" select="2014" />

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <table>
          <tr><td>Jan</td><td><xsl:value-of select="key('year', concat($year, 'jan'))/sales" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Feb</td><td><xsl:value-of select="key('year', concat($year, 'feb'))/sales" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td>Mar</td><td><xsl:value-of select="key('year', concat($year, 'mar'))/sales" /></td></tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Total</td>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="key('year', concat($year, 'jan'))/sales + key('year', concat($year, 'feb'))/sales + key('year', concat($year, 'mar'))/sales" /></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which outputs the following

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jan</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Feb</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mar</td>
    <td/>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>NaN</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

One way to solve this could be to define some variables, like so:

```
 <xsl:variable name="jan" select="concat('0', key('year', concat($year, 'jan'))/sales)" />
 <xsl:variable name="feb" select="concat('0', key('year', concat($year, 'feb'))/sales)" />
 <xsl:variable name="mar" select="concat('0', key('year', concat($year, 'mar'))/sales)" />
```

These prepends 0 onto the sales figures, so blank sales means the value is just 0. Then your total becomes this

```
 <xsl:value-of select="$jan + $feb + $mar" />
```

This assumes you don't ever have negative sales in this case. If you did have negatives, the expression could look like this (which takes into account that "not" returns 1 if true, 0 if false)

```
<xsl:variable name="jan" 
              select="concat(key('year', concat($year, 'jan'))/sales, 
                      substring('0', 1, 1 * not(key('year', concat($year, 'jan'))/sales)))" />
```

However, there is an alternate approach for doing the total. Define a key that doesn't rely on the month, just the year. In my example, I would define it like so:

```
<xsl:key name="allyear" match="a" use="@year" />
```

Then, you can make use of the **sum** function

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('allyear', $year)/sales)" />
```

You've not actually shown the xsl:key definition in your question, but assuming you defined a new key called "rows-by-locmo-all", which was the same as "rows-by-locmo" but without including the month, then you would do the total like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('rows-by-locmo-all', concat(STK_LOC_ID,yr))/Sales)" />
```

Comment: This was pretty much the answer. Thanks a lot!